# Broadcast reciever not triggering on android lollipop device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-5.0-lollipop, android-pendingintent

Here is the code for setting broadcast reciever.

```
        PendingIntent pendingIntentScheduler = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);            
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntentScheduler);
```

and the code for BROADCASTRECIEVER class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     this.context = context;        
     Log.d("onReceive", "this is broadcast reciever");        

}
```

Android Manifest Permisssions.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <application>
  <receiver android:name=".name.recieverName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.intentIWantToOpenOnRecievingBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
   </application>
```

This code is working fine with api's till 19. It is not working on Lollipop api 21. Please anyone found anything for the problem ?.

Comment: Use "setExact" instead of "set". Also, are you using "WakefulBroadcastReceiver" or "BroadcastReceiver"? On a sidenote, I have recently filed an issue that could be related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82001

Comment: Thanx for the response..I m using BroadcastReciever, should i use WakefulBroadcastReciever?.

Comment: Yes, use WakefulBroadcastReceiver, although I'm not sure if that would make any change in the behavior of a code as simple as the one above. If you want to start a service intent from the receiver though, its usage is recommended (calling the startWakefulService and completeWakefulIntent functions).

Comment: Any solution regarding this? I have the same problem now.. My codes works for years until I change my device to Android 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82001 
or 
[AlarmManager not fires on time in Android Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668444/alarmmanager-not-fires-on-time-in-android-lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmActive, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        else
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```