# AlarmManager not fires on time in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, time, alarmmanager, android-5.0-lollipop

i'm using this code to set Alarm in Android KitKat and lollipop:

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmService.this, Reciver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmService.this, 1201, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

this code is works good on Android KitKat but on Android Lollipop its fires With 10 or 5 minutes delayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug in Android Lollipop and has been reported by several other users on Android's official bug tracker. There's no immediate solution to this problem, but you can get updates regarding this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82001

Comment: but some of apps are working like this one:[link](http://cafebazaar.ir/app/com.hrmmrh.taghvim.aseman/?l=fa)

Comment: I never said setExact() doesn't work entirely, I simply said that there is a known bug in Android 5.0 that setExact() does not create a trigger on the exact time the alarm was set. Bear in mind that there's already been 3 versions of Lollipop (5.0, 5.0.1 and 5.0.2) so this bug may be specific to only one or two of them

Comment: It seems that only android 5.0 and android 5.0.1 is affected. 
Android 5.0.2 changelog says that it's fixed
http://changelog.to/aosp/aosp-LRX22C-LRX22G.html
For example on a CyanogenMod 12 device (with android 5.0.2) it works like a charm